# Mirror Bitbucket Repositories to Google Cloud Source Repositories

Tags: google-cloud-platform, bitbucket, cicd

I am trying to build CICD using cloud build in GCP. As a part of that, I am trying to mirror the repositories from Bitbucket into CSR. But I am not able to mirror the repositories. I am able to view the repositories that are present in the Bitbucket after authorizing to bitbucket from GCP.

https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/automating-builds/create-manage-triggers
https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/mirroring-a-bitbucket-repository

IAM Permissions:

I have Admin access for Source Repositories in GCP along with Cloud Build Service Account.
I have Admin access for the bitbucket repository and the workspace. The workspace in bitbucket is private.

Comment: Could you elaborate what exactly issue you've encountered? You already mention proper doc [Mirroring a Bitbucket repository](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/mirroring-a-bitbucket-repository). Did you get any error? You couldnt do some of the steps? Your bitbucket repository is cloud, not self-hosted? There is an information that only cloud repositories can be mirrored: `Only Bitbucket Cloud and GitHub Cloud repositories can be mirrorred to Cloud Source Repositories; self-hosted Bitbucket and GitHub mirroring are not supported.`

Comment: Yes, the bitbucket repository is in Bitbucket Cloud. Is it possible that we can create some policies on Bitbucket Workspaces to disable mirroring?

The Workspace I am working within Bitbucket is private.


I have followed the same steps. I am able to list the repositories which the present in Bitbucket, but when I am trying to connect it says ''' repository connection failed '''

Then I am trying to do that same from cloud build page, it says backend error.

Comment: @PjoterS any comments on this. So if the bitbucket workspace is privately secured, and only allows commits, pull, push  etc. from white listed IP's is there a way to mirror those repos

Comment: Just to confirm, you have enabled `Cloud Source Repositories API` and followed all steps from the documentation (have special account for those automated tasks), after what part you are getting this error? Do you have any entries in this whitelist with google IPs?. Is it possible for you to try mirror on dummy public bitbucket registry or swap your private registry for a few mins to public for test? Could you share full output of the error and maybe some logs (without private information)?

Comment: 1. Yes Cloud Source Repositories API is enabled.
2. Yes a special account is created.
3. Yes we have some set of IP's whitelisted for the private repository(not google ip's) 4. I have tried to mirror public repositories, it is working fine. 5. I have tested with public workspaces it is working fine. 6. The only error is "Failed to connect to repository".  7. Is there a way to white list some google ip's for mirroring ?

Answer (score 0):

Per the [Cloud Source Repositories](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/mirroring-a-bitbucket-repository#:%7E:text=If%20you%20are%20mirroring%20your%20Bitbucket%20repository%20to%20Cloud%20Source%20Repositories%20to%20integrate%20with%20Cloud%20Build%20and%20do%20not%20need%20any%20other%20Cloud%20Source%20Repositories%20features%2C%20follow%20the%20Cloud%20Build%20instructions%20on%20building%20repositories%20from%20Bitbucket%20Cloud%20instead.)

> If you are mirroring your Bitbucket repository to Cloud Source
> Repositories to integrate with Cloud Build and do not need any other
> Cloud Source Repositories features, follow the Cloud Build
> instructions on building repositories from Bitbucket Cloud instead.

The referenced guide, [Building repositories from Bitbucket Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/automating-builds/build-repos-from-bitbucket-cloud), mentions that you need to create an SSH key in order to authenticate your connection to Bitbucket Cloud.

[Bitbucket documenentation](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/troubleshoot-ssh-issues/) also confirms that the connection fails if there is no SSH key.

Comment: this is also an option, but what is the reason I am not able to mirror the repositories ? If the workspace in bitbucket has some policies set, how can we allow GCP CSR ?

Comment: @AdityaCh, having the whole error message might give us a hint about the cause. I don't see this error being related to GCP since you are following the documentation. Could you share the whole error message?

Comment: Hi @Farid Shumbar, when we click on connect repositories google console simply says repository connection failed. No specific error in the Logs as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have learned that the repositories in the Bitbucket are in Private Workspace and are IP restricted. So adding a set of Google Cloud's Public IPs solved this issue.